# How to store birthdays in a database with timezone support?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, datetime, timezone, date-fns

I am using JavaScript and a PostgreSQL database, I would like to store birthdays and notify users at 12pm in their own timezone, currently I am converting dates from their timezone to my local server time and check every hour to see if a date and time matches

```js
import { parseFromTimeZone } from "date-fns-timezone";

const userInput = "08-11" // day/month
const timeZone = "Europe/Amsterdam"
const date = parseFromTimeZone(`2000-${userInput} 00:00:00`, { timeZone });

// This is what I store in my database
const dateToStore = date.toISOString().slice("2000:".length).split(":")[0];

// This is what I run every hour
await Birthday.find({
  where: {
    date: new Date().toISOString().slice("year:".length).split(":")[0],
  },
});
```

The problem is that this solution is not very dynamic because if I migrate my server it breaks, my questions are:

- How can I store the birthdays? Assume users provide the month, day and time zone
- In what interval can / should I check to see if a birthday message should be sent? (00:00) in the user's time zone and specified date
- What would that check look like?

I have date-fns available but I do not mind using other libraries

Comment: There exists some timezones that have half an hour and not exactly 1 hout difference to the others e.g Newfoundland. So beware of this even when this cases happens seldom.

Comment: I would suggest to use UTC would be the best solution. It's a time without summer/wintertime and eyery timezone is declared with a difference to this.

Comment: Could you show an example using the date-fns library? If possible how to get the format / how to query, I am having a hard time understanding the concept which makes it hard to get the right format from user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a solution with a `account` table containing three fields:

1. `birthday`, which is of Postgres type `date`.
2. `timezone`, of Postgres type `text`. Here you'd store something like `Europe/Amsterdam`, with the important part is that it's something Postgres and your date libraries can all recognize as a time zone.
3. `last_birthday_wish_sent_at` of type `timestamptz` (shorthand for `timestamp with time zone`, which stores everything internally as UTC).

I've decoupled the birthday date from its timezone because remember that a user's birthday is always the same day anywhere in the world, even if they move around. So if my birthday is August 11th in Amsterdam, it's *still* August 11th if I move to San Francisco. Storing these components separately would allow you to reconfigure their timezone if they move.

I'd run a cron on the 0th minute of each hour that ran logic something like this (pseudocode, sorry):

```
for timezone in all timezones:
     if > 12 PM in timezone:
         for account in accounts in timezone:
             if birthday <= today AND (last_birthday_wish_sent_at IS NULL OR last_birthday_wish_sent_at < now() - '1 year):
                 send birthday wish
                 set last_birthday_wish_sent_at = now()
```

The purpose of `last_birthday_wish_sent_at` is so that you can write an algorithm that's a bit dumber and more resilient (i.e. birthday wishes still get sent even if the cron fails one hour), but still make sure to never double-send a birthday wish for any given year.

It might also be safer to model this as a separate table where you track every birthday wish you've ever sent and the user and year you sent it for. This eliminates any potential for time bugs across year boundaries.

You'd want to model the account selection and filtering in the pseudocode above as SQL so that you're not returning result sets larger than necessary. Something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM account
WHERE timezone IN ('Europe/Amsterdam', ...)
    -- note: actual date comparison a little more complicated than this
    -- because you should make sure to compare the month and day components
    -- only (probably with the `EXTRACT` function)
    AND birthday <= NOW()
    AND (
        last_birthday_wish_sent IS NULL
        OR last_birthday_wish_sent < NOW() - '1 year'::interval
    );
```

And make sure there's appropriate indexes on `timezone`, `birthday`, and `last_birthday_wish_sent`.

You could also tighten up the logic around time zone checks: it's always turning 12 PM somewhere, but it's perfectly predictable as to where that's happening so it's not necessary to check every time zone every time. You could also potentially push this into Postgres and get the whole selection logic packaged up into a single query.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, `The purpose of last_birthday_wish_sent_at is so that you can write an algorithm that's a bit dumber and more resilient`, English isn't my first language but is this something you included in the psuedo code? Also do I still need to think about leap years with this approach? Also what do the hardcoded time zones in the last snippet mean?

Comment: 1. Yes it's in the pseudo-code. The key is to make sure you check that `last_birthday_wish_sent` was not set already this year before sending anything.
2. Leap years: Good question. When extracting the month/day parts of `birthday` to compare against `NOW()`, you might want to convert any Feb 29s to Mar 1 if the conversion fails at first (trying to parse Feb 29th on a non-leap year date is an error).
3. The hard coded time interval in the last snippet is a Postgres interval , which it can parse from English. We ask Postgres: give us now minus one year.

Comment: Thank you! If you have some spare time I would like to see `It might also be safer to model this as a separate table` How this is taken into consideration if it’s really worth the extra security

Comment: The possible bug that worries me a bit is if the birthday message was a little delayed every year, and so the year check would only succeed a little later in the day every year. This could mean that theoretically, a birthday note could eventually get bumped into the next day (although admittedly, it's unlikely). A separate table could help avoid this, but so would _just_ storing a year (not a full timestamp) in `account`. The important part is to try to think about these sorts of unlikely edge cases while building your program, and try to code defensively to avoid them.

Comment: What do you mean by just storing a year? What would the format be?

Comment: The last snippet is confusing me because of the IN operator, it accepts multiple time zones but where are they coming from?

Comment: You'd probably store a year as a simple integer. And I added `IN` in case you wanted to process multiple time zones at once, but it could also just be `timezone = 'Europe/Amsterdam'` too.

Comment: I see, thank you! Then I have one last question to make it clear for me and others, if I were to store the year, how would that help me? Would I update the year the last message has been sent and where do I check? The approach sounds easier than creating a whole new table so it would be nice if the sql snippets could be adjusted to reflect those changes

Comment: Re: "*not necessary to check every time zone every time*", except that timezones extend from +14 to -10. There are also some that are on the half hour (e.g. Indian Standard Time is +5:30) and some that were at 0:15 (e.g. Lord Howe Island) so it has to check every 30 minutes (or run once per day and setup cron jobs for that day).